# Angular dependence of the element of mass of an ellipse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, integration, differentiation

I have an ellipse (a ring, not a disk; its center of mass in $C$) with a constant linear density and mass $m$, with semi-axes $a>b$; $\alpha$ is a dynamical angle describing the orientation of the body in space. $P_1, P_2$ are arbitrary antipodal points on the ellipse, with mass ${\rm d}m$ each; their location is described by the angle $\beta$.

[image]

**Question:** ${\rm d}m$ has to be somehow dependent on $\beta$ (I'll have to sum over all $P_1$, $P_2$ pairs, i.e. integrate over $\beta$), but I'm not sure how. How to relate the mass element ${\rm d}m$ with the angle $\beta$?

Comment: Hi corey979. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: I think the homework-and-exercises tag is applicable here, because you are asking about a calculation which you are trying to do: so this is an exercise. The site policy requires you to show your attempt (which you have done) but also to **ask about a specific physics concept**. I'm not sure that finding a relation between $m$ and $\beta$ is a **conceptual** issue. ... $dm$ relates to the density and volume of an element of the ellipsoid, so you need to express the volume of an element in suitable co-ordinates eg Cartesian $dx dy dx$ or spherical $r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element $dm = \lambda ds$, where $ds$ is the arc length along the ellipse. If the ellipse has equation

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$,

with $a>b$ for sake of definiteness, its parametric representation in terms of $\gamma$, the angle between the major axis and the current point on the ellipse, as seen from the ellipse center, is:

$$x = a \cos\gamma,  y = b\sin\gamma$$

from which

$$dm = \lambda \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2\gamma + b^2\cos\gamma} d\gamma$$

From your plot, it **seems** to me that $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$, from which you should be able to obtain your result. But, I repeat, I am not sure whether $C$, in your diagram, is the ellipse center, and whether the angle $\alpha$ identifies the ellipse major axis. If the answer to both questions is yes, then the above holds.